# Efficiently replace values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, replace

I am trying to efficiently replace certain values with meaningful information in a `pandas df`. Below is an example of the `df's` I'm working with.

This `df` is an example of the meaningful information. Each 3 letter code is equal to an actual place. E.g. `ABC = Home`

```
import pandas as pd

m = pd.DataFrame({
        'Place' : ['Home','Away'],
        'Code' : ['ABC','DEF']})
```

Output:

```
  Code  Place
0  ABC   Home
1  DEF   Away
```

I want to replace values `Column D` with the place information. So `Home` would replace `ABC`. There's additional items after this code but I can remove those easily enough.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({
    'C' : ['08:00:00','XX','08:10:00','XX','08:41:42','XX','08:50:00','XX', '09:00:00'],
    'D' : ['ABC-Thu','','ABC-Thu','','DEF-Thu','','ABC-Thu','','DEF-Thu'],
    'E' : ['Num:','','Num:','','Num:','','Num:','','Num:'],
    'F' : ['1','','1','','1','','1','','1'],   
    'A' : ['A','','A','','A','','A','','A'],           
    'B' : ['Stop','','Res','','Stop','','Start','','Res']
    })
```

At the moment I'm doing this manually as such,

```
#remove last 4 items
d['D'] = [x[:-4] for x in d['D']]

#replace with appropriate place
d['D'] = d['D'].replace(['ABC'], 'Home')
d['D'] = d['D'].replace(['DEF'], 'Away')
```

Output:

```
   A      B         C     D     E  F
0  A   Stop  08:00:00  Home  Num:  1
1                  XX               
2  A    Res  08:10:00  Home  Num:  1
3                  XX               
4  A   Stop  08:41:42  Away  Num:  1
5                  XX               
6  A  Start  08:50:00  Home  Num:  1
7                  XX               
8  A    Res  09:00:00  Away  Num:  1
```

But the amount of different places that need to be replaced can be up to 40-50. The codes can also change with each dataset. So `ABC` may equal `Home` one day and `Pool` the next. As you can imagine it's not very efficient to alter 40-50 different places everyday.

Is there a more efficient to loop through each code and replace with place information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need remove last `4` characters and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), last add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace non matched values to original values of `D`:

```
d['D'] = d['D'].str[:-4].map(m.set_index('Code')['Place']).fillna(d['D'])
print (d)
   A      B         C     D     E  F
0  A   Stop  08:00:00  Home  Num:  1
1                  XX               
2  A    Res  08:10:00  Home  Num:  1
3                  XX               
4  A   Stop  08:41:42  Away  Num:  1
5                  XX               
6  A  Start  08:50:00  Home  Num:  1
7                  XX               
8  A    Res  09:00:00  Away  Num:  1
```

**Details**:

```
print (d['D'].str[:-4])
0    ABC
1       
2    ABC
3       
4    DEF
5       
6    ABC
7       
8    DEF
Name: D, dtype: object

print (m.set_index('Code')['Place'])
Code
ABC    Home
DEF    Away
Name: Place, dtype: object
```

Comment: Legend @jezrael